# htaccess rewriting rules not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the following url

```
http://localhost/foldername/index.php?url=writeboard/index&step=1&id=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/foldername/writeboard/index/step/1/id/1
```

Code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:/(step)/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I tried with

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:/(step)/([0-9]+))(?:/(id)/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

it works but when the url becomes `http://localhost/foldername/writeboard/index` then I am getting 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(step)/([0-9]+)/(id)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. It works but when I am in http://localhost/foldername/writeboard/index then getting 404.

Comment: Ok see updated rule now but you didn't mention about this requirement earlier.

Comment: The page works but I am not getting the value of step and id now for this url http://localhost/foldername/writeboard/questions/step/1/id/66 when I echo url then it prints writeboard/questions/step/1/id/66

Comment: Excellent..It is working.Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `RewriteBase /foldername/` to your .htaccess file, since you're not in the top level.

More information about RewriteBase can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).

Comment: I have added that.Just the rewrite rule is not working.